# Unexpected division result in Swift

Tags: swift, division

I am trying to create a metronome application in Swift, and I'm having some awkward results. Here is the code :

```
 @IBAction func playStop(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !timer.valid{
        println(Double(60/tempo))
        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: NSTimeInterval(Double(60/(tempo))), target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }
    else{
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
func control(_control: NSControl,
    textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool
{
    if (tempoLabel.integerValue <= 0)
    {
        return false
    }
    tempo = tempoLabel.integerValue
    timer.invalidate()
    println(tempo)
    playStop(self)
    return true

}
```

The tempo is set by the user to a `NSTextfield` with number formatter, and is set to 60 by default. When the value of the text field is changed, the console explicitly writes the correct value for the `tempo` variable, and the program works fine only if the tempo is set to 60. When the value isn't 60, I get the result that `Double(60/tempo)` equals to 0, every time, and the `update` function gets called as if was in an infinite loop. Using `Double(60/tempo)`, `Float(60/tempo)` or just `60/tempo` doesn't change anything. I don't understand why I get such a result, or how I can solve it.

Comment: Try `60.0/Double(tempo)`.  Doing the division first is doing integer division which results in a whole number (zero in your case) and then casts that to a `Double`.  You want to do the division using `Double`s for both numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast numerator or denominator to double.

Do 60.0/tempo or 60/Double (tempo)